# Activate button only when form is all filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I want to add a number rule to the **Enter Admission Year** section.

A number between 250-1000 must be entered.

The button should be disabled when the wrong number is added.

Can you help me with this? A value between 250-1000 must be entered

```
    <form role="form" id="contentHoldEdu" method="post">

<input id="Name" type="text" name="name" data-required="1" class="form-control"/>
<br>
<br>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="Save" type="button">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: what have you done so far in script to achieve this effect???

Comment: and please indent your code for a better readability of your code

Comment: I can't add script codes. The site gives an error.

Comment: please try to add scripts following SP guidelines. I should work. I had the same issue once. followed SO guides for putting scripts in my Qs, it workied

Comment: I added the codes please will you check again?

Comment: your HTML has 2 elms with same IDs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a variable `status = false` in your js.

on successfull validation of each element, keep updating this variable value and at the end of the loop, if it is still true, activate the btn else let it be deactivated.

hence if it is deactivated (which it is by default) nothing will happen on submit else, the submission will work just fine.

something like below should work for you though in ur script

```
var status = true;
function on()
{
    if(document.getElementById("miktar").value.length == 0){
        status &= true;
        }
    else{
        status = false;
    }

    if(document.getElementById("saat").value.length == 0){
        status &= true;
        }
    else{
        status = false;
    }
    if(document.getElementById("dakika").value.length == 0){
        status &= true;
        }
    else{
        status = false;
    }

    if(document.getElementById("kadi").value.length == 0){
        status &= true;
        }
    else{
        status = false;
    }

  document.getElementById("submit").disabled = status;
}
```

Comment: I asked for help because I couldn't do what I wanted. I do not have the knowledge of js that can do this.

Comment: @fewcsgoempire js = javascript or JqueryScript. these scripting languages will help you programatically do what you want. We cannot help you unless you give us something to begin with. SO community helps to fix an issue. It does not do your job for you

Comment: we can only give you hints or guide you on your mission. I am afraid what you are asking is a lot of code for us to write for you.

Comment: check every elm sepearately and set status value by it, and at the end, if status if false, the btn should be disabled else enabled.

Comment: better use JQuery

Comment: my functions are working..I can't run "<select>" codes.
and I want to enter 250-1000 numbers in the id="miktar" section.

Comment: if(document.getElementById("miktar").value.length == 0) this code doesn't work with <select>.

Comment: is there anyone who can help? I couldn't solve the problem.